# Add chrome extension to an electron js application for mac osx?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, electron

I am building a small always on the top browser with electron. To show the website I am using .

Now my idea is to integrate an adblocker (preferably uBlock origin) into the browser and it should work and affect the webview. As electron is running on chrome (as far as I know) there must be a way this is possible right?

So after googling a bit, I found this:

https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#browserwindowaddextensionpath

This somehow looks like what I want to achieve. I downloaded the source of uBlock origin an added it to an extra extensions folder into the project. I ran this function both on the BrowserWindow and also my created mainWindow and both give errors or not the expected results (which means not blocking ads).

So am I doing this right? What do I need to change? Is there an easier way? Is there even a way?

Comment: I'm not familiar with electron development, but the first thing to do is universal: debug it. At least enable verbose logging to a file/terminal and see what happens.

Comment: Yes! Debugging helped me to realize that you cannot add every extension to electron, but actually just devTools extensions or extensions which don't use certain API's. The solution I found was to just use https://github.com/Jense5/electron-ad-blocker